# gradle 2.5 com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)

Tags: android, gradle, android-ndk, java-native-interface, native

I am noob in programing and I am experiencing a problem I could not find an answer for, yet.

I am trying to compile in Android Stuido 1.3.2 a modified example of the Superpowered SDK (superpowered.com).
The original example is compiled with gradle 2.2.1 and it works fine for me with the current NDK version. However, I want the debugger to work for native code and according to http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental I need gradle 2.5.

Oddly I am getting the error "*com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)*" when compiling with gradle 2.5 while it works fine with the older version. According to other similar questions this happend due to some linking error in JAVA, if more than one Java version was available (v 1.8. instead of v1.7.), however, I only have Java 8 and this is working for the older gradle version.

Can anyone help me with this issue?

My gradle 2.2.1 build.gradle code:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.superpowered.frequencydomain"
    minSdkVersion 11
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    sourceSets.main {
        jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs'
        jni.srcDirs = []
    }
}

task ndkBuild(type: Exec) {
    commandLine '/android/ndk/ndk-build', '-B', '-C', file('src/main/jni').absolutePath
    // Windows users:
    // commandLine 'C:\\Android\\ndk\\ndk-build.cmd', '-B', '-C', file('src/main/jni').absolutePath
}
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn ndkBuild
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
}
```

My Gradle 2.5. code is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'


model {
android {
    compileSdkVersion = 23
    buildToolsVersion = "23.0.1"


    defaultConfig.with {
        applicationId = "com.superpowered.frequencydomain"
        minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 10
        targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 23
    }



}

android.buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled = false
        proguardFiles += file('proguard-rules.pro')
        proguardFiles += file('proguard-android.txt')
    }
}

}



task ndkBuild(type: Exec) {
commandLine  'C:\\Users\\Dave\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\ndk-bundle\\ndk-build.cmd', '-B', '-C', file('src/main/jni').absolutePath
}
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn ndkBuild
}


dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
}
```

The other build.gradle file says for 2.2.1:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
}
```

For 2.5. it reads:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.2.0'
```

in line 6. Apart of this it is identical.

thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2):

I met the same issue with you. Adding the `compileOptions` setting in the **module's** build.gradle  fix the issue for me:

```
model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion = 23
        buildToolsVersion = "23.0.1"
        // ... 

    }

    compileOptions.with {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this same issue. Using version 0.4.0 of the gradle-experimental plugin and updating Gradle to 2.8 fixed the Java 8 build errors for me.